# How to merge two tables in postgresql when one of them is missing just one column?

Tags: postgresql, merge

Here's the thing, I have table_1:

```
id    col1    col2
A     10      20
B     15      30
C     5       15
```

And table_2:

```
id    col1    
A     10      
A     10          
D     15 
D     15    
E     25
E     25
```

I want to input on table_1 everything there is on table_2 and it's not on table_1. This is the result I'm looking for:

```
id    col1    col2
A     10      20
B     15      30
C     5       15
D     15      0
E     25      0
```

id and col1 have unique values, I mean, they might appear more than once on table_2, but they will appear with the same value.

UNION and UNION ALL will not work. Left or Right join also doesn't make sense. So I have no idea on how to do this.

If you do something like:

```
select * from table_1
union
select * from (select distinct id, col1, 0 as col2 from table_2)
```

You will get id A duplicated. So this doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a constant value and restrict from table2

```sql
SELECT id, col1, col2
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT id, col1, 0 as col2
FROM table2
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
 (SELECT 1 FROM table1
  WHERE table1.id = table2.id)
```